# Set Include in Navigation Menu to Yes in database

Tags: magento

I want to set `Include in Navigation Menu` for all categories to `Yes`.

Can anybody tell me in which table this value is?

Answer (score 1):

Magento use an eav model to save values in the database.

You have to search an attribute called "include_in_menu" in the "eav_attribute" table.

This attribute have an "attribute_id" which will be retrieve in the other tables.

On my installation, this attribute has attribute_id = 67 which is stored as an INTEGER (int)

On magento all the attributes have a type which you can find on the eav_attribute table.

You want to update your categories, we have to update the table where the integer attribute "include_in_menu" of the categories is saved.

As you can see in your database, you have a lot of tables for the categories :

catalog_category_entity, catalog_category_entity_datetime, catalog_category_entity_decimal, catalog_category_entity_int...

You have to select all your categories from the first table : select entity_id from catalog_category_entity

After you have to select the attribute_id in the table related to the good attribute type. Here is "catalog_category_entity_int" for all the INTEGER attribute...
select value from catalog_category_entity_int where attribute_id = 67 and store_id = ...

Be careful if you have multiple stores...All the stores are on the same table.

And now you just have to update value to "1" on the selected rows.

Sorry for my English, i m french...

Best regards
Cédric

Answer (score 1):

This answer worked on Magento EE 2.2.2.

Based on Cedric's answer I used the following query to remove all of the categories from the menu via Sequel Pro.

You can **remove all of your categories** from your menu by running:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int SET value='0' WHERE attribute_id='67'
```

You can **add all of your categories** to your menu by running:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int SET value='1' WHERE attribute_id='67'
```

Then flush your cache (php bin/magento cache:flush) and you should see your changes on the frontend.

Again, **be careful of what 'store_id' you're affecting**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to update all categories:

```
update catalog_category_entity_int cci
inner join eav_attribute a on a.attribute_id = cci.attribute_id
set cci.value = 1
where a.attribute_code = 'include_in_menu';
```